# reactjs-calendar-heatmap error:- TypeError: this.items.selectAll(

Tags: reactjs, charts, calendar, heatmap

I want to make a calendar heatmap in reactjs like this( https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-calendar-heatmap#example-data ) with some random data and this is what my code is.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CalendarHeatmap from 'reactjs-calendar-heatmap';
import moment from 'moment';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
//  Initialize random data
let now = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
let time_ago = moment().startOf('day').subtract(2, 'year').toDate();
let data = d3.timeDays(time_ago, now).map(function (dateElement, index) {
  return {
    date: dateElement,
    details: Array.apply(null, new Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 15))).map(function (e, i, arr) {
      return {
        'name': 'Project ' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10),
        'date': function () {
          let projectDate = new Date(dateElement.getTime());
          projectDate.setHours(Math.floor(Math.random() * 24));
          projectDate.setMinutes(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60));
          return projectDate;
        }(),
        'value': 3600 * ((arr.length - i) / 5) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3600) * Math.round(Math.random() * (index / 365))
      }
    }),
    init: function () {
      this.total = this.details.reduce(function (prev, e) {
        return prev + e.value;
      }, 0)
      return this;
     }
   }.init()
 })
this.state = {
  data: data,
  color: '#cd2327',
  overview: 'year',  //here is overview, we can change it to "global/year/month/week/day"
   }
 }
   print(val) {
    console.log(val);
    }
 render() {
   return (
    <CalendarHeatmap
    data={this.state.data}
    color={this.state.color}
    overview={this.state.overview}
    handler={this.print.bind(this)}>
   </CalendarHeatmap>
   )
  }
 }
  export default App;
```

I'm getting an error in it as shown in this image.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLUq2.jpg)

error:
    TypeError:this.items.selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...).attr(...).style(...).style(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).on(...).on(...).on(...).transition is not a function

and I don't know how to make it working. please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the error message as text in your question.

Comment: thanx @RalfStubner  for quick response. I've edited my question with error message.

Comment: the problem is in "overview" part. I'm still not able to solve this. please help me out.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code as reactjs environment